# How to use boto3 to find an EC2 jump host for ssh port forwarding to RDS?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, boto3

I want to write a script using Python and boto3 to let me psql to a specified RDS instance using EC2 as a proxy, e.g. either use `ssh -L` port forwarding or tunneling.

I have a bunch of RDS and EC2 instances.  One RDS instance may used by many EC2 instances.  This is implemented using security groups and an inbound rule that hooks up the two security groups (for EC2 and RDS) for traffic on the database port (5432).

I can use boto3 to fetch information of EC2 and RDS instances, including security groups.  But I don't know which EC2 instance I need to ssh to act as proxy for a given RDS instance.

How do I configure EC2 server to act as proxy/jump-server for my external connection through ssh ?  Which EC2 instance should I choose ?

Comment: The correct terms is "port fowarding".

Comment: If you can fetch the list of EC2 instances, and the list of RDS instances, and the list of security group rules assigned to both the EC2 and RDS instances, then what is stopping you from examining the security group rules to determine which EC2 instance can access an RDS instance?

Comment: @MarkB Nothing: I'm just lazy and expected this to be awkward.  Meanwhile I've found I can fetch the security groups, get the .ip_permissions from those and then use that to join the EC2 and RDS instances.  I'll write an answer when I've written the code

Comment: @mootmoot Yes.  Did I use a wrong term somewhere?

Comment: is your `jump` means `port forwarding`?  Since `ssh -L` is doing port forwarding.

Comment: @mootmoot "jump host" or "jump box" means a host that is used to forward traffic to work around firewall restrictions (or other restrictions, perhaps), for example by using ssh port forwarding

Comment: Then please use explicit terms like "port forwarding".  Because ssh-client can do lots of things, beside port forwarding, it possible to do ssh-tunneling, ssh reverse tunneling.  All this can be define as a  "proxy" mechanism.
Please also state the reason that why you need port-forwarding instead of connect to RDS server using SSL.

Comment: "jump host" is known terminology https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_server - maybe not as well-known as I thought?  Perhaps I should clarify: the question isn't about port forwarding: that's just the motivation.  What would make the question clearer for you (other than "this question isn't about port forwarding")?  The question was about how to pick an EC2 jump host for an RDS instance (but I think you've edited it to be about something else...?)

Comment: @mootmoot Why proxy over ssh?: because, as far as I know, nothing other than the inbound rule allows TCP traffic on that port to the RDS instance (this is the rule mentioned in part of the question that you deleted).  Would that answer your question if I added that to the question?

Comment: You can revert the edit.

Comment: @mootmoot I don't think I have permission to do that

Comment: I just add back some part I deleted. Honestly, putting RDS into same security group as the EC2 that need is basic need, it make no different if you didn't mentioned it. Unless your EC2 IP address is keep changing, otherwise there is no reason to "find" the EC2 server that enable the ssh-tunneling during startup.

Comment: @mootmoot They are not in the same security group (instead, there is a rule that connects two (VPC) groups).  I mention it in the question because some AWS documentation I found on the subject says this is only one way to do it, if I understand correctly.  Whether good or bad, this setup is not under my control.  Here's that doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html

Comment: 'this is only one way to do it' is pretty ambiguous, the documentation mentioned 7 network scenarios.  cd
IMHO. If your intention is to use your psql client connect to RDS through the EC2 ssh tunnel/ssh port forwarding/jump server, the security connection is a transparent layer. As in my answer, I already mentioned, there is too many details missing in your question, some other user just mod it down without leaving a comments.

Comment: @mootmoot: I think you misunderstand the English phrase "this is only one way to do it" (by inverting its meaning), and the point you make goes directly against your own argument from your previous comments.  Honestly, at this point I have spent more time responding to your comments than it would have taken to finish the code, so I'm going to stop now.

Comment: @CroadLangshan were you able to figure out how to do it?

Comment: @Sandhu posted an answer, sorry I didn't post it at the time!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an UNTESTED snippet that should be close to working, disentangled from actual working code:

```
import boto3

def find_jump_host(rds_name):
    rds_client = boto3.client('rds')
    ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

    rds_instances = rds_client.describe_db_instances()['DBInstances']
    for rds_instance in rds_instances:
        if rds_instance.get('DBInstanceIdentifier') == rds_name:
            break

    vpc_groups = rds_instance.get('VpcSecurityGroups', [])
    vpc_group_ids = [group.get('VpcSecurityGroupId', None) for group in vpc_groups]
    vpc_group_ids = [id_ for id_ in vpc_group_ids if id_ is not None]

    security_groups = [ec2.SecurityGroup(id_).ip_permissions for id_ in vpc_group_ids]
    group_ids = set(pair.get('GroupId')
                    for link in security_groups
                    for pair in link.get('UserIdGroupPairs', []))

    ec2_instances = ec2_client.describe_instances()
    reservations = ec2_instances['Reservations']

    for reservation in reservations:
        for instance in reservation.get('Instances', []):
            if instance['State']['Name'] == 'stopped':
                continue

            for group in instance.get('SecurityGroups', []):
                if group.get('GroupId') in group_ids:
                    break

    for instance in reservation['Instances']:
        print("Public IP", instance.get('PublicIpAddress', '<no public IP>'))
        print("Private IP", instance['PrivateIpAddress'])
        print("Public DNS name", instance['PublicDnsName'])
        print()
```

Note this makes some arbitrary decisions, like picking the first possible reservation.  Also, it's likely that some hosts will not be suitable jump hosts in your setup (for example, you may not have ssh access).  So this will require adaptation to the particular environment you're in.

Answer (score -1):

There is still many information missing here.  Please add in the details so others can mod up your question.

First, ssh-tunneling/port-forwarding answer can be found  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685664/connect-to-mysql-db-over-ssh-in-netbeans/7686384#7686384).  Just change the port from mysql 3306 to your RDS psql port.

Second, if you want to use the connection from your local PC to EC2 ssh proxy, this is only possible :

1. The EC2 server have a public connected IP address, OR
2. You have a VPN connection to EC2 server that sit on VPC private subnet

Comment: Why is this not a comment?  It does not answer the original question, nor the edited question (which, having been edited -- I'm sure with good intent -- is now about a different thing, see my comment on the question).  I can already connect from the command line, but I don't have code to find a suitable jump host.  But since I've already said I solved my own problem and will post the answer when I've coded it up: perhaps it would be better for you to wait a couple of days rather than to downvote and add an answer that does not answer the question?