# External database ssh connection in symfony parameters.yml

Tags: mysql, symfony, ssh

Anybody setup a connection to an external mysql database, only available via SSH, in their symfony app? Can this be done in the parameters.yml?

Comment: How about using a ssh tunnel instead?

Answer (score 2):

You have to open an SSH tunnel. See [Can I SSH to MySQL with the GUI tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859218/can-i-ssh-to-mysql-with-the-gui-tools) or [Access Your MySQL Server Remotely Over SSH](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/access-your-mysql-server-remotely-over-ssh/).

For parameters.yml this looks like a local MySql server, wich menans there's nothing special.

Comment: Great, thank you for the answer - makes sense. I'm also considering a VPN solution. Thanks again,