# Connect a remote mysql server to symfony(doctrine) over ssh

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, ssh, doctrine

im creating a symfony Application and I need access to a database that is on another server(via ssh). How would I do something like that?

I could'nt find any option for that in the doctrine documentation.

Comment: You need to expose the DB on the other server, then it's just as if you were connecting to localhost.
As long as your DBMS listens to an external socket (anything other than localhost) you should be able to connect to the DB, as long as you can connect to the server in general.

Answer (score 1):

if the database server not open the database port, so you must be use the ssh as the middle protocol like this.

```
$host = 'remote host';
$sshuser = 'ssh user';
$sshpass = 'ssh password';
$dbuser = 'db user';
$dbpass = 'db pass';
$dbname = 'db name';

shell_exec("ssh -p$sshpass ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -f -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 $sshuser@$host");

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=' .$dbname. '', $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

then use $dhb to interact with your database.

may be you must write some code on doctrine library for do your idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open an SSH tunnel.

See [Can I SSH to MySQL with the GUI tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859218/can-i-ssh-to-mysql-with-the-gui-tools) or [Access Your MySQL Server Remotely Over SSH](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/access-your-mysql-server-remotely-over-ssh/).

For parameters.yml this looks like a local MySql server, wich menans there's nothing special.